# Is there a clean way to make a libgdx cross-platform controls implementation

Tags: java, user-controls, libgdx

I am currently just started working with Libgdx. I reached a point where I would like to consider cross-platform (PC/handheld) issues. One important issue I can't seem to find a way around it is the following:
I don't want each controllable entity to be an extension of InputAdapter, and then contain if(PC){switch: case key: increaseSpeed(); } else if(handheld) {switch: case touch: increaseSpeed();}

Is there a to implement something so that the entities would just receive the Program-related meanings of user-inputs?

Sorry if my question is too vague :' (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally Libgdx apps just handle all the inputs, and don't worry about which device they're on.  Like this:

```
...

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Keys.RIGHT)
        increaseSpeed();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    increaseSpeed();
    return true;
}
```

This is using the event-based [`InputProcessor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) to handle input events.

LibGDX does map desktop mouse events onto "touch" events so you can collapse that part of PC/Android input handling, but there is nothing generic that maps keyboard keys to touch events or anything like that.

Comment: And, this code goes into the shared "Game" project, not into the Desktop nor the android, right?

Comment: Yeah, this is all platform-independent code for your "game" project.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this: [Interfacing with plaform specific code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code).

But in your case you would probably not use an `interface`. The basic idea is that in your different platform specific projects, you would implement an `InputAdapter`, for example `DesktopController extends InputAdapter`. Then you would supply this `InputAdapter` to your `ApplicationListener`. Somehow like this:

```
public class MyGame implements ApplicationListener {
    private final InputAdapter controller;

    public MyGame(InputAdapter controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        // this controller can now be used
        // Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(controller);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(new DesktopController()), config);
}
```

Comment: You mean that I would create the controller (that has the program-specific meanings of user-iputs) before calling the Game, and input it to the Game. Then, within the program's body,  THAT CONTROLLER should give the program program-specific meanings and NOT the user-inputs. Right?

Comment: I did not really understand that.

Comment: No problem. Thank you the effort : ) Sorry, but, I can't mark this as an answer though.